# How to test "add" in DAO without using "find" etc.?

Tags: java, unit-testing

In following code the issue is, that I cannot test **dao.add()** without using **dao.list().size()** and vice versa.

Is this approach normal or incorrect? If incorrect, how can it be improved?

```
public class ItemDaoTest {

    // dao to test
    @Autowired private ItemDao dao;

    @Test 
    public void testAdd() {
        // issue -> testing ADD but using LIST

        int oldSize = dao.list().size();
        dao.add(new Item("stuff"));
        assertTrue (oldSize < dao.list().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() {
        // issue -> testing FIND but using ADD

        Item item = new Item("stuff")
        dao.add(item);
        assertEquals(item, dao.find(item.getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you after integration or unit tests?

Comment: You tell me :) In this particular scenario - using only common sense seems more like integration test to me. But you know, after all I just want to make sure that my DAO works, that's it.

Comment: Yes it is a pain. Not sure you can end up with unit tests because of the dependency that the dao has. How does the dao work? I would personally try to avoid making your test depend on an external db and try to stub or mock the db access layer, as suggested in one of the answers. Having said that it's never as reassuring as a true db dependent integration test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your test are valid integration tests as stated above, but I would use Add to aid in the testing of of Find and vice verse.. 
At some level you have to allow yourself to place trust in your lowest level of integration to your external dependency. I realize there is a dependency to other methods in your tests, but I find that Add and Find methods are "low level" methods that are very easy to verify.
They essentially test each other as they are basically inverse methods.

Add can easily build preconditions for find

Find can verify that an add was successful.

I can't think of a scenario where a failure in either wouldn't be caught by your test

Answer (score 1):

Your testAdd method has a problem: it depends on the assumption that ItemDao.list functions properly, and yet ItemDao is the Class that you're testing. Unit tests are meant to be independent, so a better approach is use plain JDBC -as @Amir said- to verify if the record was introduced in the database.

If you're using Spring, you can relay on [AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests](http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/unit-testing-dao-classes-with-junit-spring/) to access JDBCTemplate facilities and assure a rollback after the test was executed.

Answer (score 0):

I use direct JDBC (using Spring's JdbcTemplate) to test the DAO methods. I mean I call the DAO methods (which are Hibernate base), and then confirm them using JDBC direct SQL calls.

Comment: But that means adding lines of untested JDBC code just for the sake of testing ... :|

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit under test for class-based unit testing is a class.

To see why, consider that you could, in theory, test each method of the class in isolation from all other methods by bypassing, stubbing or mocking them. Some tools may not support that; this is theory not practice, assume they do.

Even so, doing things that way would be a bad idea. The specification of an individual function by itself will vary between vaguely meaningless and verbosely incomprehensible. Only in the pattern of interaction between different functions will there exist a specification simpler than the code that you can profitably use to test it.

If you add an item and the number of items reported increases, things are working. If there is some way things could not be working, but nevertheless all the patterns of interaction hold, then you are missing some needed test.